# ROS diamondback compilation problem on Gumstix

Tags: ros, gumstix, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a Gumstix Overo Fire installed Ubuntu 10.10. Approximately two weeks ago I managed to compile and install ROS-base (dimaondback); however, I could not compile ROS yesterday. It gave me an error related to insufficient memory related to cc1plus. You can view compile output at the following URL. How can i get rid of this error? This is very important for me. I have to compile and install ROS on my Overo.

Compile output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/609252/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9982/ros-diamondback-compilation-problem-on-gumstix/) by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-05-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on 2011-05-18**:
There is nothing taking up RAM. I have no swap space. How can i configure a swap space for Overo?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-17**:
Do you have any swap configured for the Overo? Do you have anything else open on the Overo that might be taking up RAM that the ROS compilation needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've dealt with this issue through using swap partition. For the instructions to configure swap space on Ubuntu click the following link:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man8/dphys-swapfile.8.html

---

Originally posted by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) with karma: 46 on 2011-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on 2011-05-23**:
[2] - http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

**Comment by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on 2011-05-23**:
[1] - http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=Installing_Ubuntu_10.04_on_Gumstix_Overo

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-23**:
link 1?  link 2?

**Comment by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on 2011-05-23**:
First install ubuntu (my choice is 10.10)[1]. Then continue with ROS installation on Ubuntu from source tutorial at [2]. This is exactly what I have done. Sorry for this short explanation, I haven't enough time. If you have got any question, i will try to explain..

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-23**:
Would you mind either posting a tutorial or a listing of links on how, from start to finish, you got ROS running on the Gumstix?  I'm just about to get started doing the same on an Overo Tide (same processor, more RAM, no DSP) and it'd be nice to have a better sense of how to do this.

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-19**:
I figured.  :)

**Comment by [dirtyibt](https://answers.ros.org/users/136/dirtyibt/) on 2011-05-19**:
The one posting to the Gumstix mailing list is me too ;)

**Comment by [Bradley Powers](https://answers.ros.org/users/501/bradley-powers/) on 2011-05-19**:
Interesting.  I just saw this on the Gumstix mailing list too.